# Justified Itemized List

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

i would like to have a justified list, so that each item in the list is justified within a specified column. For example, if i had the list

```
 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 2. cu sed laoreet debitis evertitur
```

it would format it so that it would be something like:

```
 1.Lorem   ipsum  dolor  sit   amet
 2.cu sed laoreet debitis evertitur
```

I'm currently just used the `\itemize` command.

Comment: Will your items contain paragraphs, or just a single line of text?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of each paragraph, TeX inserts a space of `\parfillskip`, which has a default value of `0pt plus 1fil`. If you change this value to `0pt`, the last line will be flush right. So if you add

```
\parfillskip=0pt
```

at the start of each list, your list items will be fully justified as desired.